# Pending migration error for undefined method - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fixing an error I made in naming a column type in my database table from an integer to datetime.  However, I get a pending migration error after I run rake db:migrate after writing the following. When I added the new migration via rails g MigrateDeliveryTimeDates, no new file was generated under db/migrate so I created it manually. The error reads:

```
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `deliverytime_temp'
```

Here is my db/migrate file:

```
class ChangeColumnDeliveryTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :deliverytime_temp)
    add_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :datetime)  
  end
end
```

Here is the migration I added (rails g migration ChangeColumnDeliveryTime):

```
class ChangeColumnDeliveryTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
   change_column(:deliveries, :deliverytime, :datetime)
  end
end
```

Here is my db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160216220012) do

  create_table "deliveries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "deliveryaddress"
    t.integer  "deliverytime"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  add_index "deliveries", ["order_id"], name: "index_deliveries_on_order_id"

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.datetime "date"
   t.string   "name"
   t.string   "pickup"
   t.datetime "pickuptime"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[change_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column)** method instead **[`add_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column)**

```
def change
  # rename_column :table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
  rename_column :deliveries, :deliverytime, :deliverytime_temp
  change_column :deliveries, :deliverytime_temp, :datetime
  # change_column :table_name, :column_name, :new_data_type
end
```

Comment: When I make these suggested changes, save them, and run rake db:migrate, I still get the following error:  "rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `deliverytime_temp' for #<MigrateDeliveryTimeDates::Delivery."  I'm still not sure why.

Comment: @Codestudio : ok then put `change_column :deliveries, :deliverytime, :datetime` before `rename_coulmn`

Comment: also remove `ChangeColumnDeliveryTime` migration file